# No such file or directory inside app.asar (electron/nodejs)

Tags: python, node.js, electron

I am building an electron app which runs off nodejs. The gui runs off the html/js, and I also have a few python scripts which run in the background which show data to the user.

It runs fine when I run locally with `npm start`, but when I choose to package the app with the `electron-packager` library, the python does not run, and cannot be found inside the `app.asar`

I believe the solution revolves around using `const originalFs = require('original-fs');` and `originalFs.readFileSync(FILE);` but I am brand new to a lot of the deploying side of things, I don't know if I'm headed in the wrong direction, or if this is impossible at all. My code is below:

```py
    const subprocess = spawn('python', ['-u', __dirname + "/python/myscript.py", arg])
    subprocess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`data:${data}`);
    });
    subprocess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`error:${data}`);
    });
    subprocess.stderr.on('close', () => {
        console.log("Closed");
        app.quit()
    });
```

I have also tried setting `--asar=false` and going into the /resources/app/ folder to get to the `myscript.py` file. This gives the app full functionality, however, I still want to be able to pack it all away into the `asar.app` if possible.

Answer (score 3):

To run your python inside your Electron app. 
Please compile your python file to excutable binary file and make your electron app to embed this bin file. So that this electron app will be runnable at any devices even if python is not installed at that device. This will be more comfortable.

using **pyinstaller** to compile as executable binary file.
So you can add **electron-builder** configuration like this to store this bin out of asar.

```
"build": {
    "extraResources": [
        {
            "from": "bin",
            "to": "bin"
        }
    ]
}
```

After pack this will copy the bin folder to **/resource/bin**
So that to run the bin file

```
let extension = '';
switch (process.platform) {
  case 'darwin':
  default:
    break;
  case 'win32':
  case 'win64':
    extension = '.exe';
    break;
}


const basicURL =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? path.join(__dirname, '../../bin')
    : path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'bin');

const binURL = path.join(
  basicURL,
  `bin${extension}`
);
spawn(binURL, params);
```

I recommend **electron-builder** rather than **electron-packager**

Answer (score 0):

There should be 2 paths one for dev build and the other for production. In this example the paths may not be exactly what you want but should put you on the correct track. In production mode the getAppPath() function will give you the path to the app.asar file.

```
const getPythonPath = fileName => {
    const path = require('path')
    const isDevBuild = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'

    if (isDevBuild) {
        return path.resolve(__dirname, `./python/${fileName}`)
    } else {
        const { app, remote } = require('electron')
        // check main or renderer process for app path
        const appPath = app ? app.getAppPath() : remote.app.getAppPath()
        return path.resolve(appPath, `./python/${fileName}`)
    }
}

const subprocess = spawn('python', ['-u', getPythonPath('myscript.py'), arg])
```